# Using background image on Safari iOS looks ugly

Tags: html, ios, css, image, safari

I'm trying to fix the background image. On other devices is displayed well... but in Safari iOS looks very ugly. The code is as follows:

```
.main {
    background: url('imgs/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Thus it is seen:
[image]

The code is here: https://github.com/lozanotux/lozanotux.github.io

SOLUTION (CSS):

```
.main {
    background: url(../imgs/bg.jpg);
    background-color: #444C5C;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    zoom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What *should* it look like?

Comment: thus: [https://i.imgur.com/89cinQX.png](https://i.imgur.com/89cinQX.png)

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: contain`?

Comment: Yes: [https://i.imgur.com/tunQcan.png](https://i.imgur.com/tunQcan.png)